# Find out compression ratio for each part of a file

Tags: compression

I have some data that I compress in-memory before writing to disk, and I would like to make the compressed file as small as possible. The context is a video game save system. I can remove some parts of the uncompressed file, but I would like to know how to guide my efforts, by finding out which parts of the uncompressed data contribute most to the final compressed file size.

I know I shouldn't just remove the things that are most numerous, since they often prove to be very compressible and will not take up much space in the resulting compressed file.

I imagine that it's possible to, for each byte in the uncompressed data, calculate how much that byte contributes to the overall compressed file size. Programs like 7-zip show you how much files in an archive are compressed - this is just taking that to the extreme!

I don't know quite enough about compression to know if this is a sensible thing to ask for - but as far as I understand, this could be done by dividing the cost of each byte amongst each used 'reference' to a byte block that the byte is contained within. More frequently repeated blocks would have their cost lowered, and more unique blocks (with no references) would not have their cost lowered.

Does this make sense, and are there any algorithms for doing this kind of thing?  The compressor in this case is LZ4 (for speed), but I would like a general answer if possible - if there is no way to do this for LZ4, but it's easy with other compressors, I'd still very much like to know.